# iOS Restore Auto Renewal Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

It's ok call `restoreCompletedTransactions` method once the user opens the app?

Or should Should I enqueue the method invocation in a background thread? Is it consider a blocking thread?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    registerForPushNotifications()
    handleRemoteNotifications(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    LoveSubscriptions.store.requestProducts(nil)
    LoveSubscriptions.store.restorePurchases()
    return true
}
```

Comment: It's not blocking but the user might get those annoying "Login with iTunes" prompts when they open the app which can be a bad UX. What are you trying to accomplish by auto restoring? Usually it's triggered by the user tapping a "Restore" button.

Comment: After uninstall and then install the app again the older receipt is not loaded. I need to restore it to then send it to my server and verify it.